# IUIAutomation trying to find a focused element is on the Microsoft Outlook ribbon

Tags: c#

Using automation I am successfully finding the focused element using the code below but I am trying to ascertain whether the focused element is on the Microsoft Outlook ribbon. I am trying the code below as one example but having little success

```
if (process.Equals ("Microsoft Outlook"))
{
    lowerRibbonMenuCondition = _automation.CreatePropertyCondition
        (UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_NamePropertyId, "Lower Ribbon");
    //this line works fine    
    IUIAutomationElement element = _automation.GetFocusedElementBuildCache(cacheRequest);
    //this line doesn't
    IUIAutomationElement lowerRibbonElement = element.FindAll(TreeScope.TreeScope_Ancestors, 
        lowerRibbonCondition);
    if (elementArray.Length > 0)
      MessageBox.Show("focused element is on the ribbon", "Testing");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MSDN documentation of FindAll:

> Blockquote

This function cannot search for ancestor elements in the Microsoft UI Automation tree; that is, TreeScope_Ancestors is not a valid value for the scope parameter.

> Blockquote

So obviously this can't be used here. In addition you use lowerRibbonCondition in your call to element.FindAll while you create a condition called lowerRibbonMenuCondition, although that might be a typo here. You can use the following example from MSDN to walk the automation tree upwards and modify it to check each parent element for its name you find the ribbon bar or reach the root: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff625922(v=vs.85).aspx#WalkAncestors   You should first use Microsoft SDK's Inspect tool to see that Outlook ribbon's name property is actually "Lower Ribbon".